# Windows Phone não carrega .font em CSS

Tags: html5, css3, twitter-bootstrap, windows-phone, css-font-face

Estou fazendo uma aplicação HTML5 *responsive*, utilizando o Bootstrap e SmartAdmin, etc.

Funciona em todos dispositivos. Inclusive Internet Explorer 8, 9, 10 e 11 porém no Windows Phone 8 (com aquele último update que fica com o IE 11) não roda as fontes `FontAwesome Icon` e `Glyphicons Icon`

http://lythos.wmb.com.br/

Transformando os icones em quadrados.

No emulador do IE11 no meu Windows 8.1 diz que funciona.

Como corrigir? Algum emulador melhor para eu poder testar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Descobri, o servidor não estava reconhecendo a fonte http://lythos.wmb.com.br/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff com o cabeçalho mime, normalmente isso não seria problema porém para o IE, foi. ao adicionar o cabeçalho no servidor IIS tudo foi corrigido.

Answer (score 3):

Só para completar, talvez tenha sido seu problema ou pode ser de mais alguém com  IE e Fonts. O IE e Firefox bloqueiam as fontes que vem de CDN ou outro domínio por causa de *same-origin policy*, já tive esse problema no passado e é bom tomar cuidado.